# How to select part of an array and filter in Mongo?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection in Mongo that contains documents that look like this:

```
{
    name: "Bob",
    destinations:
    [
        {
            city: "Dallas",
            state: "Texas",
            isBusiness: "true",
        }, {
            city: "San Diego",
            state: "California",
            isBusiness: "true",
        }   
    ]
},
{
    name: "Sue",
    destinations:
    [
        {
            city: "Las Vegas",
            state: "Nevada",
            isBusiness: "false",
        }, {
            city: "Sacramento",
            state: "California",
            isBusiness: "true",
        }   
    ]
}
```

I want to query this collection so that I receive the `name` of each person along with the `city` of each destination within the state of California, but not the `isBusiness` value which should be ignored.

The result of the query should be:

```
[
    {
        name: "Bob",
        city: "San Diago",
    },
    {
        name: "Sue",
        city: "Sacramento"
    }
]
```

This example is a bit contrived, but how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite basic aggregation, not sure what to explain about it:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$destinations"},
    {$match: {"destinations.state":"California"}},
    {$project: {_id:0, name: 1, city: "$destinations.city"}}
])
```

Docs:

- https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/
- https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/
- https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/
- https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collectionName.find({"destinations.state":"California"},{name:1,"destinations.city":1})
```

Comment: This is not quite right.  It does correctly extract the `city` from the `destinations` array, but it still returns all the cities, not just the ones in California.

Comment: yep. the posted answer with aggregation is your solution.

Answer (score 0):

$elemMatch operator of MongoDB is used to apply filter over an array of elements.

According to description as mentioned into above question please try find executing following find operation into MongoDB shell.

```
db.collection.find({
    destinations: {
        $elemMatch: {
            state: "California"
        }
    }
}, {
    'destinations.$': 1,
    name: 1,
    _id: 0
})
```